# SimpleITK - how to get maximum and minimum intensity in Image?

Tags: c#, itk, simpleitk

I have some DICOM images. I want to rescale them using `IntensityWindowingImageFilter`, but first, I need to know initial values of maximum and minimum intensities.

Right now, I am building WPF UI, with which I want to have some sliders to allow user to interactively input parameters for this operation. However, to have best user experience available, I need to limit scale on sliders to have maximimum and minimum that is maximum and minimum of intensity of image. In ITK, I could use `MinimumMaximumImageCalculator`, but I can't seem to find it in SimpleITK.

Of course, I could simply use `Image.GetBufferAsXXX()` and simply iterate over each pixel to find those values, but I am almost sure this is not a right way to go.

Comment: And, BTW. can somebody add SimpleITK tag? I do not have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One can use `MinimumMaximumImageFilter`. I am not sure why thing used to get minimum and maximum is a filter, but well...

Usage:

```
MinimumMaximumImageFilter filter = new MinimumMaximumImageFilter();
filter.Execute(image);
this.ImageHighestIntensity = filter.GetMaximum();
this.ImageLowestIntensity = filter.GetMinimum();
filter.Dispose();
```

Comment: Glad that you have found answer to your own question. ;)

Comment: Well, it was kind of obvious. It had happened twice or thrice before for me, that I fought some problem for a while, asked a question here, to get an answer mere minutes later. But I hope somebody might find it useful someday, so I left it here.